# How to set search_type with Elasticsearch PHP SDK

Tags: php, elasticsearch, sdk

I would like to set the search_type with the PHP SDK of Elasticsearch.

At the moment my params looks like this:

```
$params = [
  "from" => 0
  "size" => 20
  "_source" => [...]
  "body" => [
    "query" => [
      "bool" => [
        "must" => [
          "multi_match" => [
            "query" => "searchTerm"
            "fields" => [...]
            "operator" => "and"
            "type" => "cross_fields"
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
];
```

According to this issue https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/issues/121 I simply have to add the search_type to `$params`

```
$params['search_type'] = 'dfs_query_then_fetch';
```

Also I tried to add it to the body

```
$params['body']['search_type'] = 'dfs_query_then_fetch';
```

Both options are invalid and return a `BadRequest400Exception`.

According to the repository, it is possible to add the parameter.
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/blob/master/src/Elasticsearch/Client.php#L915

Here it says `enum` as data type.
What exactly is `enum` in PHP? And what is it in this particular situation?

Does anyone have an example for me, how to add the search_type correct?

Thanks in advance.